# access a variable value(which is in loop) from .aspx.cs page to java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am having loop in my .aspx.cs file.

```
foreach (DataRow DRow in DT_Test_Question.Rows)
{
    Question_ID = DRow[1].ToString();
}
```

I want to access Question_ID in java script without postback, but Question_ID gives me the last value. How to get all the values of Question_ID?

Comment: You can have a hidden field which can hold all the `Question_ID` comma separated.

Comment: tried with hidden field, again it gives me the last value only

Comment: Can you tell us what are you doing against the loop. Populating a repeater? or creating some html on run time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use following code for aspx.cs file

```
public string Question_ID = "";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (DataRow DRow in DT_Test_Question.Rows) 
   {
        Question_ID += DRow[1].ToString() + ",";
   }
}
```

use following code for aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var Question_ID = '<%=Question_ID.Trim(',')%>'.split(',');
  .
  .
  // you can use Question_ID is array of string
</script>
```

Note: Question_ID must have value before you want to use it in javascript, so assignment will be done on page_load / init method. Also note Question_ID must be a public variable to access it in javascript.

Comment: too fast for me :) this is the way i wanted to suggest as well, + 1

Answer (score 0):

Have a hidden field to hold all the Question_ID as below...

```
StringBuilder question_IDs = new StringBuilder();

foreach (DataRow DRow in DT_Test_Question.Rows)
{
    if (DRow[1] != null)
    {
        Question_ID = DRow[1].ToString();
        if (question_IDs.length == 0)
            question_IDs.Append(Question_ID);
        else
            question_IDs.Append("," + Question_ID);
    }
}

hdnField.Value = question_IDs.ToString();
```